# Link path for redirect

Tags: java, servlets, redirect, path

I'm trying to redirect my response but I got stuck at the link path.

The following command takes me to the tomcat's localhost and searches for the page there but it can't find anything, as expected.

```
response.sendRedirect("/myPage.html");
```

In order to manage this problem I have to put my root folder name (the one from webaps) in the link path, but I don't think that's a really good idea.

```
response.sendRedirect("/mySite/myPage.html");
```

Why is this happening? Is there any other way to solve this problem, besides getRequestURL() or something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A relative redirect URL is relative to the current request URL (the one as you see in the browser address bar). The leading `/` will take you to the domain root. The behaviour is perfectly predictable and normal. If the `myPage.html` is in the same folder as the current request URL, then you can just remove the leading `/`:

```
response.sendRedirect("myPage.html");
```

Or if that is never reliably predictable because the current request URL can come from anywhere in your webapp, then just dynamically include the context path:

```
response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/myPage.html");
```

Comment: Thank you very much! And I would guess that the second approach, using it with the context path, it's considered good practice, right?

Comment: Yes, this way you don't need to hardcode the context path nor to worry about the relativility of the path of the incoming request URL as compared to the redirect URL.